# Check if a column has more than one value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a *dataframe* in which I only want to run a function on if I know that in certain columns (say there are 11 columns and I want to know this on 4 of them) there is more than one value (e.g. they are not all 2).

Is there any specific function to find this out or would I have to loop through each of the columns and check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sapply` to loop over the columns, get the `unique` elements in each column, check whether the `length` is greater than 1.  It gives a logical vector which can be used for subsetting the dataset if needed.

```
i1 <- sapply(df1, function(x) length(unique(x)) >1)
df1[i1]
```

---

Or another option to subset columns will be `filter`

```
Filter(var, df1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For each column run `length(unique(x))`. This will print the number of unique columns. If you provide more information this can be nested into a function that decides whether or not to run based on the sums of `length(unique(x))`.